# Sum amount of table where a particular column has same value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to find the sum of amount in the table according to the value of month. This is my query

```
SELECT to_char(
          to_timestamp(
             date_part('month', p.date_from)::text,
             'MM'
          ),
          'Month'
       ) as Month,
       p.employee_id, p.id as payslip_id,
       p.date_from, p.date_to, pl.amount
FROM hr_payslip p
   INNER JOIN hr_payslip_line pl
      ON (p.id = pl.slip_id AND pl.code = 'NET');
```

Output:

[image]

Need:

I need to group by the month and sum value of column amount.

Comment: Why not use `GROUP BY` and `sum`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe actually I odnt know to do this, here months contains all inputs not february only, so how to group by here

Comment: something like? `SELECT month, SUM(amount)
FROM hr_payslip
GROUP BY month`

Comment: But while using inner join , hoe to do this, really i am not good in psql @Jim Jones

Comment: `SELECT to_char(
          to_timestamp(
             date_part('month', p.date_from)::text,
             'MM'
          ),
          'Month'
       ) as Month,
       SUM(pl.amount)
FROM hr_payslip p
INNER JOIN hr_payslip_line pl ON (p.id = pl.slip_id AND pl.code = 'NET');
GROUP BY month`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the following query

```
select to_char(to_timestamp (date_part('month', p.date_from)::text, 'MM'), 'Month') as Month, 
sum(pl.amount) from hr_payslip p
INNER JOIN hr_payslip_line pl  on (p.id = pl.slip_id and pl.code = 'NET')  group by month
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple `GROUP BY` is all you are asking for:

```
SELECT to_char(p.date_from, 'Month') as month,
       sum(pl.amount)
FROM hr_payslip p
   INNER JOIN hr_payslip_line pl
      ON (p.id = pl.slip_id AND pl.code = 'NET')
GROUP BY to_char(p.date_from, 'Month');
```